# How to do multiple nested route with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

is that posible to create Nested Routes more then 2?

i want to create something like this:

```
+--------------------+
| User               |
| +----------------+ |
| | Profile        | |
| | +------------+ | |
| | | About      | | |
| | | +--------+ | | |
| | | | Detail | | | |
| | | +--------+ | | |
| | +------------+ | |
| +----------------+ |
+--------------------+
```

so in the web will be like this

link: `/localhost/user`

web display:

```
USER
```

link: `localhost/user/profile`

web display:

```
USER
  PROFILE
```

link: `localhost/user/profile/about`

web display:

```
USER
  PROFILE
    ABOUT
```

link: `localhost/user/profile/about/detail`

web display:

```
USER
  PROFILE
    ABOUT
      DETAIL
```

any example code with jsfiddle will be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You just have to nest the corresponding routes (obviously you would also need the user's `id` parameter):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'profile', component: Profile,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'about', component: About,
                  children: [
                    {
                      path: 'details', component: Details,
                    }
                  ]
              }
           ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Same code, but just condensed (maybe it helps to read better):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [{
        path: 'profile', component: Profile,
          children: [{
            path: 'about', component: About,
              children: [{
                path: 'details', component: Details,
              }]
          }]
      }]
   }]
})
```

Comment: Hi @billal-begueradj ! could you also explain how to switch routes in child pages with multiple pages in template using router-view

Comment: Could you improve the answer adding also the case where root paths or intermediate paths are not accessible because don't make sense? In this case a "fuzzy" component is mandatory? why a redirect is not enough?